# set/ put a cat among the pigeons

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This common proverb or idiom is found in many languages. It is used in English, to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throw_the_cat_among_the_pigeons), to mean "cause an enormous fight or flap, usually by revealing a controversial fact or secret", or in other words: to do something suddenly or unexpectedly which leaves people worried or angry. The key point being the making explicit a controversial or precarious paradigm or settlement”. The same article gives equivalents in other languages, as, for example, Dutch, German, Spanish and Russian. But I can’t for the life of me, find any equivalent Latin proverb or expression. Have colleagues any suggestions? I have trawled through Erasmus’s Adagia and several other dictionaries I have to hand but in vain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be better matches, but I suspect on some occasions it might work and hence worth throwing in: **miscere caelum terris** (to mingle the heavens with earth), or *miscere caelum ac terras*.

We thus find in Lewis & Short in *[misceo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=misceo)* (see examples there):

> Of storms, to throw into confusion, to disturb, confound, embroil (poet.) [...] Hence, of persons, to raise a great commotion, make a prodigious disturbance, to move heaven and earth.

In Livy we [can see this this expression](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Liv.%204.3.6&lang=original) used to vent one's anger and accuse opposition in introducing  great disturbance:

> quid tandem est cur **caelum ac terras misceant**, cur in me impetus modo paene in senatu sit factus, negent se manibus temperaturos, uiolaturosque denuntient sacrosanctam potestatem?

> And what in the name of goodness is it for which they **embroil heaven and earth**? why was almost an attack made on me just now in the senate? why do they say that they will not restrain themselves from violence, and threaten that they will insult an office, sacred and inviolable?  (D. Spillan)

---

If we are not restricted for idioms, we can simply leave the *caelum ac terras* part aside. ***miscere*** alone is a very good option to use here.

Meissner has this in his Latin phases book: "to cause universal disorder: *omnia turbare ac miscere*"

> omnia turbare ac miscere

Comment: Thanks, d_e, This is a very useful idiom and I shall learn it forthwith. I wondered whether something like lupus inter oves is an idea worth working on but it does not seem to be used proverbially and in any event signifies carnage rather than universal disorder.

Comment: Perhaps a lower register idiom, which is metaphorical, might be plaustrum perculi. Thanks d_e.